# Does throwing an error from set() guarantee that the model will not be saved to the database?

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, sequelize.js, joi

I am using a schema validator to validate and clean up a JSON schema before it is set. It performs the validation and spits out a clean version (if valid) all in one step, so it would be redundant to use it in both the `validate` and `set()` properties. There's no need to do it twice.

Does throwing an error from set() guarantee that the model will not be saved to the database?

Here's the column from the model for example:

```
metadata: {
  type: DataTypes.JSONB,
  set(obj) {
    const { error, value } = schema.validate(obj)
    if (error) throw error
    this.setDataValue('metadata', value)
  },
},
```

Comment: To re-phrase my question then, and to address my chief concern, I would ask, does throwing an error from `set()` guarantee that the model will not be saved to the database?